# Java Interface in a project involving fractions

Tags: java

I am having trouble in figuring out why the line of code
that says Fraction Interface f =  etc... does not work. The problem is in 
.denominator and .numerator. 
It seems that I am not supposed to implement get methods. So, how I am going to access the denominator and the numerator of aFraction?

Below you also see the methods in the interface.
Many thanks.

```
public class Fraction implements FractionInterface, Comparable<Fraction> {


    private int numerator;  
    private int denominator;    

    public Fraction()
    {

            numerator = 0;
            denominator = 1;
    }   

    public Fraction(int num, int den)
    {

            numerator = num;
            denominator = den;
    }   




    public FractionInterface add(FractionInterface aFraction)
    {
                // return a new Fraction object
                // a/b + c/d is (ad + cb)/(bd)
                // implement this method!

             // WHY .denominator and .numerator do work ?

                FractionInterface f = new Fraction((numerator*aFraction.denominator))
                + (aFraction.numerator * denominator) , (denominator *aFraction.this.denominator));

               return f
        }

}
```

```
public interface FractionInterface {
    /** Task: Sets a fraction to a given value.

        public void setFraction(int num, int den);


    public double toDouble();


    public FractionInterface add(FractionInterface aFraction);


    public FractionInterface subtract(FractionInterface aFraction);


    public FractionInterface multiply(FractionInterface aFraction);


    public FractionInterface divide(FractionInterface aFraction);


    public FractionInterface getReciprocal();
}
```

Comment: On a wing, try setting different accessibility modifiers for them, e.g change them to `public`

Comment: "Does not work" means what? Please add stacktrace. You use aFraction.this.denominator- change that to aFraction.denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Give your interface getter method signatures for the numerator and denominator,

```
public int getNumerator();
public int getDenominator();
```

implement these in your concrete class, and then call these methods when you need a numerator or denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a method `getNumerator()` that calls the `numerator` variable from `this`. So when you call `this.getNumerator()`, it calls the variable `numerator` associated with the given fraction. This is especially useful when dealing with more than one fraction in a method. Creating a `getNumerator()` method is as simple as

```
public int getNumerator(){
  return numerator;
}
```

since it just needs to grab the member variables(you don't need to initialize anything). Do the same for the denominator. Now you can call both as `foo.getNumerator()`.